# How can i delete directories including the files inside?

Tags: c#, winforms

I did that:

```
if (se.textfilessendended == true && se.photossendended == true)
            {
                Directory.Delete(temptxt);
                Directory.Delete(tempphotos);
                Directory.Delete(outputtext);
                Directory.Delete(outputphotos);
            }
```

But on the first Delete im getting error say: Directory is not empty.

Comment: Side note the `== true` are pointless.. `if (se.textfilessendended && se.photossendended)`

Comment: @Sayse They also aren't inherently bad. If someone wants them for readability, that's fine...

Answer (score 3):

Try this instead:

```
            Directory.Delete(temptxt, true);
            Directory.Delete(tempphotos, true);
            Directory.Delete(outputtext, true);
            Directory.Delete(outputphotos, true);
```

You can pass a `bool` as the second parameter for the [`Delete`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f.aspx) method, which should delete files and folders recursively if said `bool` is `true`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Directory.Delete(outputtext, recursive)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/fxeahc5f.aspx) overload.

If you set `recursive = true` this method will go recursively down to tree of directories and remove them.

In other words write:

```
   Directory.Delete(temptxt,true);
   Directory.Delete(tempphotos,true);
   Directory.Delete(outputtext,true);
   Directory.Delete(outputphotos,true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
        Directory.Delete(temptxt, true);
        Directory.Delete(tempphotos, true);
        Directory.Delete(outputtext, true);
        Directory.Delete(outputphotos, true);
```